# How Mysql's master-master replication ensures data consistency

Tags: mysql

When using Mysql master-master replication, how do you ensure data consistency if there are writes to both master databases? Will there be data conflicts?

Comment: This question would be better received on the "Database Administrators" Stack Exchange site ... where you already have 4 questions, two of which I've commented on to request further details ... 

Comment: @matigo, thanks.